# AsyncAPI Websockets Spring generated code and implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, asyncapi

I want to generate code from AsyncAPI specification and try out how it works. My goal is to have only 1 socket open for each client and over that connection send/receive different types of messages. I couldnt find any example that would show me how to generate the code and run it.

Here is the API yaml

```
asyncapi: '2.3.0'
info:
  title: demo
  version: '1.0.0'
  description: websocket demo

servers:
  test:
    url: localhost
    protocol: ws

channels:
  data:
    publish:
      operationId: publishData
      message:
        $ref: '#/components/messages/dataMessage'
    subscribe:
      operationId: subscribeData
      message:
        $ref: '#/components/messages/dataMessage'

components:
  messages:
    dataMessage:
      headers:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/MessageHeader"
      payload:
        oneOf:
          - $ref: "#/components/schemas/FirstPayloadType"
          - $ref: "#/components/schemas/SecondPayloadType"

  schemas:
    MessageHeader:
      type: object
      properties:
        messageType:
          enum:
            - a
            - b
            - c

    FirstPayloadType:
      type: object
      properties:
        x:
          type: string
        y:
          type: number

    SecondPayloadType:
      type: object
      properties:
        op:
          type: string
        tar:
          type: string
```

Then i use https://github.com/asyncapi/generator to generate the java code from this yaml with

```
ag asyncapi.yaml @asyncapi/java-spring-template
```

And thats where Im stuck, it uses springframework messaging and i dont know how to configure/implement it while using the generated message handler. Or maybe im missing something in the yaml so it doesnt generate properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the template does not support anything other than [`Kafka`, `AMQP`, and `MQTT` protocols](https://github.com/asyncapi/java-spring-template/blob/ae864fb1a1f1ad47b801caf843947e3caf91550e/package.json#L46).

As of this writing, there does not exist any template for you to generate Java code for the WebSocket protocol.

If you want the template to support the protocol, please create a feature request for it.

Or you could [author your own template](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator/blob/master/docs/authoring.md) if you'd like.